# LDAP in php command line application

Tags: php, yii, ldap

can we use LDAP in command line applications?

because when I tried to use it, PHP gave me this error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()
```

help ??

Comment: Is your php compiled with LDAP support?

Comment: Yes, I use it with Yii web application normally.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you either have 2 different PHP-applications or two different php.ini-files.

When you get the message `Call to undefined function ldap_connect()` that means, that your current PHP can not find the function which can be defined in an extension. So either the extension is not loaded in your CLI or you are using a different PHP in your CLI then in your WebServer.

To check which extensions are available in your CLI you can do a `php -i | grep -i ldap` which should give you some lines containing ldap. When you do not get any input, have a look where your PHP-binary is located by calling `which php`. That should give you an idea of where your CLI-PHP is located. Have a look in your WebServer config to see where that PHP comes from and you might solve the issue.